# Finding alternate selectors from contains

Tags: jquery, cheerio

I have a list of elements obtained through the `contains` selector.
Let's say I want to know how to access a person's name on a profile page. I can test my own profile with my own name.

`let name = $(':contains(jamie)');`

I'd like to store a selector based on the above results that could be used to retrieve the name from any profile.

Without walking the DOM and calculating a selector, is there another way to get a (single or list) selector to each element that comes out of the `contains` query?

Comment: *"Without walking the DOM and calculating a selector..."* Why not? Seems like the most straight-forward approach.

Comment: I don't think I understood your question. Can you create a fiddle(not a problem if it's not runnable) exhibiting what you want to do with some comments included there.

Comment: what does `store a selector` mean?

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder. That's pretty much what I'm doing. I'm wondering if there are other, more sophisticated or jQuery-like ways to get there. Possibly not though.

Comment: @charlietfl In my specific case I'm storing selectors in a database.

Comment: @charlietfl: Say Jamie finds that his name here: `<span class="profile">Jamie Dixon</span>`. He wants to figure out a selector for that that *doesn't* use "Jamie", like `span.profile`, so he can use that to process other profiles than his and extract information from them.

Comment: A selector in Javascript is always a string. I'm storing it in a DB. I'm not storing a variable name in a database. A selector looks like this `"#fooId"`. That's what I'm storing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that walks up the parents of a single element and stops if ID or body is encountered.

It will create selectors like:

```
#test > div:eq(0) > ul:eq(0) > li:eq(2)
```

JS

```
var $el = $('li:contains(3)');
var selectors=[];
selectors.push(getSelector($el));

$el.parents().each(function(){
    var $node = $(this);
    selectors.push(getSelector($node));
    if($node.is('body') || $node[0].id ){       
        return false
    }    
});

var selector = selectors.reverse().join(' > ');
console.log(selector);
/* test selector in DOM */
$(selector).css('color','red')


function getSelector($el){
    var id = $el[0].id;  
    if(id){
       return '#' +id;  
    }        
    if($el.is('body')){
       return 'body';
    }        
    return $el[0].tagName.toLowerCase() +':eq(' + $el.index() +')';        
}
```

With an extra loop it can be made to combine multiple elements with same selector format into a comma separated selector

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldb53sLt/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a unique attribute to each prospective element; could then get , set element by filtering unique attribute value

```js
$(function() {
var elem = "<span class=profile data-uuid=123>Jamie Dixon</span>"
$("body").append(elem);
// `let` name ..
var name = $.map($(":contains(Jamie Dixon)"), function(uuid, i) {
  return $(uuid).data("uuid")
});

$("[data-uuid=" + name[0] + "]").css("color", "blue"); // do stuff
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```