# Getting the element that the plugin was binded to in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been making my first `jQuery` plugin and I need to add some CSS in the `head` via a styles tag as doing inline css on the element which gets injected by the script has some weird bugs in IE8 - 10.

But to add the styles in the head I need to target the actual element that the user binded the plugin to.

For example:

```
$('input').myPlugin(); // I need to get the text "input"
$('#form .foo').myPlugin(); // I need to get the text "#form .foo"
```

Is it possible to get this data within the plugin?

Comment: In case you need it you can walk up the parents and create selector strings ... see my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28881979/1175966

Comment: Why not do the CSS for a specific class unique to your plugin, then add that class to the elements as you're initialising your plugin for them?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Hmmmmm I guess that's a possible idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### $.myPlugin

The recommended way to solve your problem is using `this` and other methods described below. If you require the selector as a string, you can define the function as a child of jQuery (`$`) and have the function executed in a similar way to jQuery's &.ajax and $.extend. What this is doing is it is making it a child of jQuery, and a child of `$.fn` so it can still be 'classified' as a regular jQuery plugin, or a prototype of jQuery. When you old set your plugin the `$.fn`, it is set to jQuery's prototype, making it so you have to run the jQuery function. Here we are doing that, but because functions are also objects, we can set that function to $.myPlugin making it still part of jQuery, but prevents the user from entering the selector twice. Since `this.selector` s deprecated *(and it'll probably be removed soon)* it's better than running it through a function to generate a selector.

```
$.myPlugin = $.fn.myPlugin = function (selector) {
    console.log(selector);
}

$.myPlugin('#selector'); //Logs: '#selector
```

> The *$.fn* is completely optional and is there just in case a user forgets to execute the function using `$.myPlugin(selector)`  the function will still work when using `$().myPlugin(selector)`

### Other alternative

If you don't require the string, I would recommend using jQuery's [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) or similar functions ([here](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)) along with `$(this)`.

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function () {
    var $this = this;
    var filteredElements = $this.children('a');//

    console.log(filteredElements);
} 
$('#form .class').myPlugin();
//Logs: children that are <a> of #form .class
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of `$(this)`, but I really do need the string. Don't really want to rely on the user providing it either, was hoping there would be a simple way to get it.

Comment: @Brett You could also ask the user to provide it as a function of `$.fn` as `$.fn.myPlugin('#selector')`

Comment: You mean instead of calling it like `$('#selector').myPlugin()` you would do it that way?

Comment: @Brett Yeah pretty much. You could also do `$.myPlugin = $.fn.myPlugin` at the end of your code so it would be just $.myPlugin

Comment: Alright cool - perhaps you can update your answer with this solution?

Comment: Could you detail it a bit more for the chosen solution and mention the extra optional stuff like `$.myPlugin = $.fn.myPlugin`?

Answer (score 1):

That string is the selector property of the object:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(){
    console.log(this.selector);
}
$('#form .foo').myPlugin(); // logs '#form .foo'
```

But using it looks like a bad practice (and it's also deprecated, as pointed by charlietfl, for good reasons). You shouldn't need it. To style the elements you can directly do

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(){
    this.css('color', 'red');
}
```

Comment: `.selector` is deprecated...also removed as of 1.9

Comment: That's what I am doing to set the inline css, but as I said it causes some strange behaviour in certain IE versions with regards to padding text fields/textareas when they are set to `box-sizing: border-box;`. If you manually set the padding it works fine.

Comment: @charlietfl Apparently still accessible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964760/alternative-to-selector-property-now-that-it-is-removed-in-jquery-1-9 ? See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0ea8c32863af31fb5cfc184e8d513bbae35583e8/src/core/init.js ; try, at `console` , same page `jQuery().jquery; $("body").selector;`

Comment: @guest271314 yup but when documentation says it's deprecated you can't expect it to always be available in future releases. I was simply quoting what it says in the docs

Comment: @charlietfl See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0ea8c32863af31fb5cfc184e8d513bbae35583e8/src/core/init.js

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
$.fn.myPlugin = function(sel) {
  console.log(sel, $(this));
};
var selectors = ["input", "#form .foo"];
$(selectors[0]).myPlugin(selectors[0]); // I need to get the text "input"
$(selectors[1]).myPlugin(selectors[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<input type="text" />
<form id="form">
  <select class="foo" name="foo">
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks.... but got a bit too much returned. For an `input` I got this returned: `["input#.form-control", "input#.form-control", "input#.form-control", "input#.form-control", "input#."]`

Comment: Didn't change the output I got; though my test scenario is over a number of input fields. I checked the console for your one above and the first output `input` but the second output `select.foo` rather than `#form .foo`.

Comment: @Bret See updated post. See also http://api.jquery.com/selector/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500246/how-do-i-get-a-jquery-selectors-expression-as-text/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535967/destination-div-disappearing-in-simple-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but as per my comment to @vihan1086 I didn't really want to have to get the user to provide it as a parameter.

Comment: Tried @dystroy 's answer ? Though `.selector` documented as deprecated ,  appear to still be accessible; see `$.fn.init` https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0ea8c32863af31fb5cfc184e8d513bbae35583e8/src/core/init.js